# Why do I get run-time error '2759' when saving the record? access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Using Access 2010, I have a form for `Purchase_Orders` where the `status` changes depending on the whether the `Items` in the sub form have been delivered or not, and, it is influenced by the date as well.

```vb
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim var_Delivered As String

var_Delivered = "SELECT Count(*) AS d_Count" & _
            " FROM Items" & _
            " WHERE PO_ID =" & Me.PO_ID.Value & _
            " AND Supplier_Dnote_ID IS Null" & _
            " AND Delivered_Without_Dnote =0;"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(var_Delivered, dbOpenDynaset)
'MsgBox rs!d_Count
   If rs!d_Count > 0 Then
        If Me.Supply_date < Date Then
            Me.Status = "Overdue"
        Else
            Me.Status = "Submitted"
        End If
   Else
        Me.Status = "Delivered"
   End If

db.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

This runs after_update of the `Purchase_Orders`. I have a `save_close` button that uses the following code and doesn't return an error:

```vb
If Me.Dirty = True Then
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Purchase_Orders", acSaveYes
Else
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Purchase_Orders", acSaveNo
End If
```

However, I also have a `Save` button that doesn't close the form. This is where I get run-time error 2759 : The method you tried to invoke on an object failed. Debug Highlights the saverecord line.

```vb
Private Sub SaveOnlyBtn_Click()
If Me.Dirty = True Then
    docmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End If
End Sub
```

If I comment the status code out and use the save button, the record saves fine without any errors. Why do I get this error? I'm completely stumped and searching the error online hasn't helped me either.

Comment: Try `Me.Dirty = False` instead of `docmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`. Does this help?

Comment: I tried this and I got a different error. I think it was run-time error 57097.

Comment: Is your form `Purchase_Orders` bound to a table and if so is the field `status` bound to a field from that table?

Comment: yes, this is correct. The form is bound to purchase_orders table and the control source to status is a field also called status.

Comment: I think `acCmdSaveRecord` is essentially the VBA-way of clicking "save" from this menu in the Access ribbon: http://i.imgur.com/3ASr7Wt.jpg These buttons (including the save button) get greyed-out (become unavailable) in certain situations where they are not appropriate. Have a look at the save button on the ribbon before you run the save and check whether it's available.

Comment: Also, probably unrelated to your issue, you should take a look at how to close and dereference recordsets (`rs`) and databases (`db`): http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Recordsets_for_Beginners#Cleaning_Up_a_Recordset_Object

Comment: so I should `rs.close` and not `db.close`? I have found that part of my issue lies in the fact I used the code in the `form_afterUpdate` event. I have successfully made a work around using a public sub and called it on the required fields. I'll try and post when I get chance.

Comment: Yes. You need close anything you've opened and destroy anything you've created. You've opened `rs` with `OpenRecordset` so you need to do `rs.Close`. You've not opened `db`, so there's no need to close it. Then you need to destroy both `rs` and `db` by setting them to `Nothing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found that the error did not occur when I put the code in the "on dirty" event, which then made me realise that I don't need necessarily have to run the code after the form updates, only when specific fields change. So I changed my code to a public code and called it when `supply date`, `delivered_without_dnote`, or `supplier_Invoice_ID` changed.

the public code is :

```vb
Public Sub delivered_status()

On Error GoTo errTrap1

If Forms!Purchase_Orders_Ex.Form!Status = "Cancelled" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim db As Database
    Dim var_Delivered As String

    var_Delivered = "SELECT Count(*) AS d_Count" & _
                    " FROM Items" & _
                    " WHERE PO_ID =" & Forms!Purchase_Orders_Ex.Form!PO_ID.Value & _
                    " AND Supplier_Dnote_ID IS Null" & _
                    " AND Delivered_Without_Dnote =0;"

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(var_Delivered, dbOpenDynaset)
    'MsgBox "Outstanding Items: " & rs!d_Count
        If rs!d_Count > 0 Then
            If Forms!Purchase_Orders_Ex.Form!Supply_date < Date Then
                 Forms!Purchase_Orders_Ex.Form!Status = "Overdue"
            Else
               Forms!Purchase_Orders_Ex.Form!Status = "Submitted"
            End If
        Else
            Forms!Purchase_Orders_Ex.Form!Status = "Delivered"
        End If

    rs.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End If

errTrap1:
    Select Case Err.Number
         Case 3314 'form not complete and other required fields are empty
            Exit Sub
        Case Else
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
               MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
            End If
    End Select

End Sub
```

Now, when I use either the `save_close` or `Save_Only` I do not get error 2759. I do not completely understand which part of my original method caused the error but it no longer occurs with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this issue and moving code out of Form_AfterUpdate fixed it for me too.

What's (vaguely) interesting is that the code in question worked fine locally, but did not work when deployed to the client.  I tried importing just the amended form instead of replacing the whole access app, but I still got the same issue.  I also copied the back-end database back from the server to my development machine, but still didn't get the issue locally.  On top of that I did endless compact/repair and decompile/compile.

My conclusion at the end of all of that was that this was yet another weird issue emanating from the Access black-box, rather than an issue with the particular code.